# Remove special character from data frame in R before and after text

Tags: r, special-characters

I have the following data frame

```
1   +PAL+PEA+ + + +
```

I want to remove the '+' before and after the text and get something like

```
1   PAL+PEA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
gsub('^[+]*|[+ ]*$', '', str1)
#[1] "PAL+PEA"
```

#### data

```
 str1 <- '+PAL+PEA+ + + +'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
regmatches(str1,gregexpr("[aA-zZ]+[+]{1}[aA-zZ]+",str1))
[[1]]
[1] "PAL+PEA"
```